# Conditionally format a column based on the present day of the week (calculated in another cell)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am building a table for work with weekly tasks. I want today's task only to appear in bold, while other weekly tasks in gray/dimmer color so to be less evident.

I created a separated, single cell where I write `=NOW()`, and which returns me the day of the week in `1-7 format`. (let's call this cell A1).

On the columns of interest, I tried to create a conditional formatting rule that is `=A1=1`. 1 would be `Monday`. I'd like to only format the other column if `A1=1`, therefore if it's Monday. But It doesn't work.

I also tried with `=$A$1=1`, or `=$A1=1`, unfortunately It doesn't works also?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You're asking for today's day of the week, but it sounds like that isn't really what you want.  If today is Monday, you probably don't want the tasks from every Monday past and future, just today's tasks (or a specified calendar date).  The approach would be similar to Rajesh S's answer, but you need to specify the appropriate condition (that answer gives you what you asked for, but I'm guessing you didn't ask for what you need).  Can you clarify the question?  That will help get you the answer you need, and make it clearer for other people with a similar requirement who land here.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, will help you to fix the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select `L2:M11` and reach to **Conditional 
  Formatting, New Rule**.
- Apply this Formula: `=Weekday($L2,2)=1`.
- Click **Format** button, select an appropriate 
  format and finish with **Ok**.

**N.B.**

- `WEEKDAY` Formula has many Pattern for 
  Weekdays , I've selected `2` is  `Monday to Saturday`.
- You may select any one which is applicable to 
  your work practice.

**For rest of the Rows, which has Weekday other than Monday, you need to apply this Formula.**

`=Weekday($L2,2)<>1`.

*You get this:*

[image]

*Adjust cell references in Formula as needed.*